# Chosen search does not work with Jquery Dialog. Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-chosen

Here is my code

```
  var dlg = $("#transfer_client").dialog({
                dialogClass: "templateDialog",
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                zIndex: 1500,
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                title: "Transfer Campaign to a different Client"
            });

        dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
```

Where transfer_client is div code is:

```
 <div id="transfer_client" class="dialog position" title="Transfer to a different Client">
    <span>Client:</span>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Height="30px" ID="ddlClients" DataTextField="ClientName"
        DataValueField="ClientID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmSubmit();" ID="btnTranfer"
        Text="Transfer" OnClick="btnTranfer_Click" />
</div>
```

I have tried `$("#dropDownID").chosen()`, after `dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));`
or before but it does not make it searchable. But the code works fine when used without any dialog. Any idea how to make it work inside dialog?

**Edit**: Marking as solved as this was a bug in dialog js.

Comment: dialog() is not part of the standard jQuery. You must be using some sort of plugin or would have written  it yourself (the extension), care sharing the code for dialog() ?

Comment: I am using dialog as http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at [issue #18 on github](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/18)?

It solved my similar issue and basically comes down to increasing the search box's CSS `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 23423423423;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.